# Get Attribute variable passed from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

All, I have a attribute variable set in the servlet. and want to get it in the jsp.
But I have some questions about it. 
Say you have the code .

In the servlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("BeerSelected", "BlackBeer");
        RequestDispatcher disp=request.getRequestDispatcher("SelectResult.jsp");
        disp.forward(request,response);
    }
```

In the JSP

this code works

```
<%String name = (String)request.getAttribute("BeerSelected");%>
<%= name%>
```

But why below code doesn't work? jsp doesn't render the value .

```
<%request.getAttribute("BeerSelected");%>
```

Neither does below code.

```
<%request.getAttribute("BeerSelected").toString();%>
```

I don't know why `toString()` doesn't work. thannks.

Comment: Please read up to date JSP tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because to send something to the response writer, you must use `<%= ... %>`, or explicitely write to the writer:

```
<% out.println(request.getAttribute("BeerSelected")); %>
```

Your code is equivalent to the following Java code:

```
request.getAttribute("BeerSelected");
```

So this calls the method, but doesn't do anything with what it returns.

That said, you should forget completely about scriptlets, which shouldn't be used for years and years. Use the [JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to display (and correctly escape) your value:

```
<c:out value="${BeerSelected}" />
```

Also, an attribute is, by convention, spelled like a Java variable: `beerSelected` and not `BeerSelected`.

Comment: :p Forgive me I am a newbie from ASP.Net web application to Servlet. thanks your nice answer. +1